# Flutter | Row too big to fit into CursorWindow

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, large-data

I'm developping a flutter app and I use standard SQLite database to store information from sensors.
I'm getting the error:

```
E/SQLiteQuery(11895): exception: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=3; query: SELECT sessionId, deviceId, startDate, endDate, ... , timestamp FROM sessions
E/flutter (11895): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=3) sql 'SELECT sessionId, deviceId, startDate, endDate, ..., timestamp FROM sessions'}
```

While I'm trying to read data saved in a table "sessions" with a large content.

> 5 sensors of 3 dim array, every 100ms, during 30min, but could be more ...  **> 300 000 numeric data** per session (Up to 10Mo).

How to avoid this *'row to big'* of error ?

Comment: do you have any blob fields in your `sessions` table?

Comment: Literally `blob`, of course not. They all have specific names, look at the SQLite query  : `SELECT sessionId, deviceId, startDate, endDate, ... , timestamp FROM sessions`

Comment: For large row they are JSON stringified 2 dimentional arrays. Lets call them `rowA, rowB, rowC,rowD`. Containing : `"[[95,90], [96,95], ... ]"` for exemple with shape (X,Y) where Y is known, but X is variable.

Comment: and they are huge in size? like one or two MB for example?

Comment: Max 2Mo, per row. Meaning max 10Mo max per session.

Comment: That's why you have that exception - one row cannot be that big - I don't remember the current limit but it was 1 MB in the past

Comment: You're probably right. I've seen something like this somewhere... so how should I manage this amount of data in SQLite ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=3; query: SELECT sessionId, deviceId, startDate, endDate, ... , timestamp FROM sessions` points that you're trying to fit the rows on a CursorWindow. Last time I recall CursorWindow (buffer) has 2Mb available.

One way to circumvent this issue is by reducing the columns used in the query. You may also want to keep track of the stored data to be extracted, to avoid surpassing the CursorWindow limit.